# iam using firebase firestore (flutter) dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i want to get user type field from firestore to route the user to either (Store owner page ) or (Customer page ) ?
[image: firestore]

**I want to get the value to decide which page the user should see**

[image: i tried this function but it didnt work]

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to get the `userType` field directly from the `DocumentSnapshot`, which will return `null`, you need to get data of field from the `Map<String, dynamic>` which is returned from `data()`, so you need to change:

```
userType = documentSnapshot['userType'];
```

with this:

```
userType = (documentSnapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['userType'];
```

this will save the value of **userType** field in the `userType` variable.